# Batched numpy array indexing

Tags: python, numpy

I have source and destination numpy arrays, say

```
dest = np.arange(1000)
src = np.random(500)
```

I want to copy across the src to the dest array overwriting the first 50 numbers, then all the numbers starting at index 100 to 150, then from 200 to 250 and so on till 900 to 950.

To calculate the index I use the following:

```
index = np.reshape([100*i+np.arange(50) for i in range(10)],-1)
```

then I just use

```
dest[index]=src
```

to copy across the remaining elements (with another src, say src2), i just adust the index

```
index2 = np.reshape([50+100*i+np.arange(50) for i in range(10)],-1)
dest[index2]=src2
```

I'm pretty sure there's a more elegant/efficient way of achieving this without having to explicitly build the indexes.

Is there a better way to perform the copy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dest.reshape(-1,50)[::2] = src.reshape(-1,50)`

And for `src2`:

`dest.reshape(-1,50)[1::2] = src2.reshape(-1,50)`

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest would be to reshape both into matrices

```
dest = dest.reshape((10, 100))
src = src.reshape((10, 50))
```

and use matrix indexing

```
dest[:,:50] = src
```

The idea is to create a 100 x 10 matrix of `dest` and replace the *left* half with `src` converted to a 50 x 10 matrix.

---

**Edit**

@Haminaa's answer is slightly faster.

```
%timeit dest.reshape((10, -1))[:,:50] = src.reshape((10, -1))
```

> The slowest run took 11.54 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 1000000 loops, best
>   of 3: 1.55 µs per loop

```
%timeit dest.reshape(-1,50)[::2] = src.reshape(-1,50)
```

> The slowest run took 12.97 times longer than the fastest. This could
>   mean that an intermediate result is being cached. 1000000 loops, best
>   of 3: 1.38 µs per loop